# One button goes to different activities

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to make a one button goes to different activities, I have uploaded an image to show how I planned to do.

The idea is to come from `Activity 1` or `Activity 2` and find the same **Layout** and **Button** and go through it to `Activity 7` or `Activity 8` according to the Activity I was on.

I hope that I have explained my idea with a good way to be understood.

[image]

Comment: I am making an app, with too many activities, and i wanted to reduce the number of activities by doing this idea.

I am about to start 

    `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }`



        `public void btn_next1 (View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }`

what i need to do next?

Comment: you can add all the three buttons in your Base Activity and extend every activity with your Base activity and then you can use buttons by your choice anywhere

Comment: Can i specify that i came from a specific button instead of an activity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an identifier or key with intent from your 1st part of activities as shown in the image and based on that key identify where the activity came from and where is it supposed to go. You can use if statements inside your button click function
Example

in xml for all your 3 button

```
<Button
android:name = "@id/button1"
android:onClick = "button1">
```

define other button and their properties

in java file

```
    public void button1(View v)
    {
        Intent i = getIntent()
        String key = i.getStringExtra("key");
        if(key == "activity5")
        {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity5.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
        else if (key == "activity6")
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity6.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can i have an example?

Comment: Thank you man, i am having with your code: a " variable i is already defined in Scope"